# Playing/Pausing Music Using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I've been working on code to pause and play music and I'm stuck because it works perfectly when the mp3 is hosted online (Dropbox) but when I tested it with a local file it doesn't pause, it replays the track.

HTML:

```
<a class="music" data-audio="mp3/Zone.mp3" title="Play/Pause"></a>
```

CSS:

```
.music:before {
content: url("../img/music.png");  
}  
.music.on:before {
content: url("../img/pause.png");  
}  
.music.on:after {
content: url("../img/VS.gif");  
display: block;
cursor: default;
opacity: 0.7;
}
```

JS:

```
;(function() { 
var AUD = document.createElement("audio"),
BTN = document.querySelectorAll("[data-audio]"),
tot = BTN.length;

function playPause() {
var src = this.dataset.audio;
if(AUD.src != src) AUD.src = src;
AUD[AUD.paused ? "play" : "pause"]();
for(var j=0;j<tot;j++) if(BTN[j]!=this) BTN[j].classList.remove("on");
this.classList.toggle("on");
AUD.addEventListener("ended", playPause);
}

for(var i=0;i<tot;i++) BTN[i].addEventListener("click", playPause);

}());
```

I have no idea what's causing this, could someone help?

Comment: check your browser's console for error/warnings, it could be possible that your file is not loading.

Comment: @azs06 thanks for replying, I already checked the console and there's no error, and it can find the file and play it, but it won't pause local files.